# How to exclude or include a package from a JPA persistence unit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my application I have two distinct sets of entities, and for each of them I want to use a separate persistence unit.

How can I make it so each persistence unit only handles part of the entities I have annotated with `@Entity`?

I have them distributed in two distinct packages, so I was planning to do something like this in the two `orm.xml` i have:

```
<entity-mappings>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>first_schema</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

    <package>example.package.first</package>
</entity-mappings>
```

and

```
<entity-mappings>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>second_schema</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

    <package>example.package.second</package>
</entity-mappings>
```

But it does not work

Comment: The two persistence units are defined, with their list of entities, in the persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
we can configure one or more persistent units in same persistent.xml
```

as below and create entity managers for each with @PersistenceContext(unitName="...") to access from dao.

```
xml configuration:
-------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit1">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>Datasource</jta-data-source>
        <class>Entity1</class>
        <class>Entity2</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
            ....etc
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit2">

    </persistence-unit> 
    //and so on 

</persistence>

Dao service
-------------
 @PersistenceContext(unitName="persistenceUnit1") 
 EntityManager entityManager;
```